# Function bounded below by square root near 0. How fast can Fourier transform go to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

If $f \geq 0$, $f=0$ outside $(-1/2,1/2)$, and $f \geq cx^{1/2}$ on $(-1/4,1/4)$, is it possible to have $|\hat{f}(k)| = O(|k|^{-1})$? How fast could $\hat{f}(k)$ goes to zero?

Comment: One can easily show that $\sum_{n \ge 1} n^{-3/2} \sin nx \sim c\sqrt x$ for $x$ near $0^+$ so one can modify that easily away from $0$ to satisfy the OP and the coefficients are clearly $\sim n^{-3/2}$ which is the best we can do, so yes we can have $|\hat{f}(k)| = O(|k|^{-1})$ and even $|\hat{f}(k)| = O(|k|^{-3/2})$ but not better